# In MVC assigning value to session giving Object reference not set to an instance of an object exception

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, wcf

**Problem Statement:**

Authenticating Login Credentials through WCF Service.Based on the Login ID authentication, calling method in one more controller for assigning Customer ID to Session gives null reference exception.What i'm doing wrong?

**WCF Service Code:**

Here i'm able to validate user and get customer details based on login id.

```
public bool IsValid(LoginDC objLoginDC)
{
    try
    {
        var result = dbEntity.CustomerUsers.FirstOrDefault(m => m.LoginID == objLoginDC.LoginID && m.Password == objLoginDC.Password);
        
        if (result != null)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }

    }
    catch
    {
        return false;
    }
}

public IEnumerable<CustomerUserDC> GetLoginCustomerUserDetails(LoginDC objLoginDC)
{

    return (from tu in dbEntity.CustomerUsers.AsEnumerable()
            where tu.LoginID == objLoginDC.LoginID && tu.Password == objLoginDC.Password
            select new CustomerUserDC
            {
               CustomerID = tu.CustomerID,
                UserID = tu.UserID,
                Name = tu.Name

            }).ToList();

}
```

**Login Controller:**

Here i'm calling Login Authentication and getting Customer details method of WCF. I'm able to get values from WCF,but i'm not able to assign values to session.

```
public ActionResult Index(LoginModel loginModel, string returnUrl)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        objLoginDC.LoginID = loginModel.LoginID;
        objLoginDC.Password = loginModel.Password;
        if (objSvcMasterConfig.IsValid(objLoginDC))
        {
            var varLoginCustomerUserDetails=objSvcMasterConfig.GetLoginCustomerUserDetails(objLoginDC);
            objGenController.GlobalSessionCustomerUserDetails(varLoginCustomerUserDetails);
            FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(objLoginDC.LoginID, objLoginDC.RememberMe);
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }
        else
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "The Log In ID or Password provided is incorrect.");
        }
    }

    return View(loginModel);
}
```

**General Controller:**

Here i'm not able to assign the value which are getting from WCF Service in Login Controller,giving Object reference not set to an instance of an object exception in General Controller.

```
public void GlobalSessionCustomerUserDetails(dynamic varLoginCustomerUserDetails)
{
    Session["TempCustDetails"] = varLoginCustomerUserDetails[0].LoginID;
}
```

Comment: To me, it seems like `varLoginCustomerUserDetails` is null or an empty list.

Comment: @DZL-No, varLoginCustomerUserDetails is having value.I have checked in immediate window. Leave about varLoginCustomerUserDetails, even if i assign any string(ex: Session["TempCustDetails"]="Hi")it shows the same error.None of the values are getting assigned to session, why??

Comment: Where are you declaring `objLoginDC` in your Login Controller?  Could that be null?

Comment: @DStanley-No, varLoginCustomerUserDetails[0].LoginID is having value.I have checked in immediate window. Leave about varLoginCustomerUserDetails, even if i assign any string(ex: Session["TempCustDetails"]="Hi")it shows the same error.None of the values are getting assigned to session, why??

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the return type to List<>...
public List GetLoginCustomerUserDetails(LoginDC objLoginDC)

Comment: Why i should change var(dynamic) to list??? Leave about changing return type to listvarLoginCustomerUserDetails, even if i assign any string(ex: Session["TempCustDetails"]="Hi")it shows the same error.None of the values are getting assigned to session, why??

Comment: If I didn't mention clearly....I said "return type" (IEnumerable<CustomerUserDC> to List<CustomerUserDC>), not "parameter" (dynamic to List).